# named entity tagged corpus

Tags: entity, corpus

I am looking for named entity tagged corpus for English news domain in text and speech (transcribed) at same period of time. If anybody has any information about the corpus please send me the link.

Thanks
Khadaka

Answer (score 3):

I've found the [Open American National Corpus](http://www.anc.org/annotations.html) to be quite useful. They do provide a [named-entity tagged portion](http://www.anc.org/annotations/OANC-bbn-entities.zip) containing both news text and transcribed speech, but note that it's tagged using the BBN NE Tagger, not an army of people. I've had decent results bootstrapping other models using this kind of corpus, though.

Best of luck. I'd be curious to hear of your results.

Comment: Hi Curtos, I was curious if you had any resources for bootstrapping other models?